# Timeout of an binary file with python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

Hello I'm new to python language and I would like to know how to stop the execution of the binary file when it reach the timeout for example a code that doesn't work as I want

```
import os
time = os.system("./test")
if (time > 10):
    print ("timeout")
else:
    #do other stuff
```

Inside test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
       printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

In this example I want to run the binary made by test.c and stop the execution of test when the the time reach 10 seconds since I run the binary file.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`subprocess.Popen.poll`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['./test'])
t = time.time()
while time.time() -t < 1:
    if proc.poll() is not None:
        # Do other stuff
        break
else:
    print 'timeout'
    proc.terminate()
    proc.wait()
```

If you could you Python 3.3+, [`subprocess.Popen.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) which support `timeout`:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['./test'])
try:
    proc.wait(timeout=10)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('timeout')
    proc.terminate()
    proc.wait()
else:
    # Do something else.
```